# Spring boot @Caching With Multiple Keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

```
public class Student {
    public int studentName;
    public String Addr1;
    public String Addr2;
    public String Addr2;
    //getter setter
}

I have one repository class which contains following methods
class StudentRepoImpl{
   @Cacheable(value = "Students")
   public List<Students> findAllStudents() {
     //fetching all cust and putting in the Students cache
   }

   @Cacheable(value = "Students")
   public List<Students> findStudentsBystudentNameAndAddresses() {
     //fetching all cust data by **Name/Address1/Address2/Address3** basis of field available studentName/Address1/Address2/Address3 and putting in Student table
   }

}
```

Current Output :

1. Fetch All data from DB and adding in Students cache in **findAllStudents() method**
2. But while searching for data based on some criteria (Name/Address1/Address2/Address3) using **findStudentsBystudentNameAndAddresses() method** it is fetching data from DB instead of cache.

Note: Not added Key while caching because there are 4 fields in search criteria (Name/Address1/Address2/Address3) and these are conditional fields means some time only Address1 will be in search criteria or sometime Address1+Address2 or sometimes all Address1+Address2+Address3 fields and I want to fetch exact match on the basis of Name and available Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

did you add @EnableCaching annotation in your configuration class

Answer (score 0):

Try to add configuration like this

```
@Configuration
public class CachingConfig {
    @Bean(name = "springCM")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("Students");
    }
}
```

Hope useful